# Chrome Remote Desktop - can't unlock screen (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, remote-desktop

Initially I installed Chrome-Remote-Desktop, enabled my remote computer and accessed it with no problem. 
BUT, then while in my remote desktop session, the screen timed-out and the session on the remote computer locked and I can't get back in with my user password. Is there some kind of session log that I can reset to get back in?